# What alternatives to ANDROID_ID can be used with Android LVL?

Tags: android, android-lvl

Due to the well known issue of Secure.ANDROID_ID not being unique what alternatives are there for identifying a device in LVL?

If I were to use an installation unique generated ID would that not cause issues for the user who has purchased the app? E.g. if they re-install or switch devices will they have to re-purchase the app because the ID has changed?

```
// Try to use more data here. ANDROID_ID is a single point of attack.
String deviceId = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should generally provide more context when asking a question: this single line doesn't mean much. *Assuming* you are referring to the LVL sample app, this `deviceId` is only used to derive an encryption key for obfuscating the app's preferences. Actual purchases are tied to the user's Google account, not to their device. So if they change devices *and* use the same account, purchases will be restored.